# Transition from a gradient to a non-gradient background on hover

Tags: html, css

I am using a gradient to set the background color on one element. The thing is, I am also having an "`hover`" background but not using the gradient. At the minute, when I hover on an element having the class `.tinted` it flashes as it first display no background and then apply the `rgba(0,0,0,0.65)`
Is there any way that the transition could directly go from background: `gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.65), rgba(0,0,0,0.30))` to `rgba(0,0,0,0.65)` ?

```
.tinted {
    transition: background-color 500ms linear;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,.65), rgba(0,0,0,.30));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,.65), rgba(0,0,0,.30));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,.65), rgba(0,0,0,.30));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.65), rgba(0,0,0,.30));
}

.tinted:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `gradients` with `background-image` and the `plain color` with `background-color`:

```
.tinted {
    transition: background-color 500ms linear;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,.65), rgba(0,0,0,.30));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,.65), rgba(0,0,0,.30));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,.65), rgba(0,0,0,.30));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.65), rgba(0,0,0,.30));
}

.tinted:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/sq2zpdb8/)

Comment: It does work, but by doing so, the gradient is still there on hover.

Comment: You can't apply a transition on `background-image`, so this is the best you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This Is What you Can Use For This Approach:

```css
#box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: orange;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, crimson 0%, transparent 100%);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#box:hover{
    background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Do You Always Write In Camel Case For Everything?

Comment: @ibiza yes. Almost always

Answer (score 0):

A posibility is to set a gradient that has 2 parts, one with the color changing, and the other with a constant color.

And change the part of the gradient that you are showing with background-image.position

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100% 0%;
  transition: background-position 1s;
  margin: 10px;

}

.test:hover {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}

#test2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, red 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test" id="test2"></div>
```